# Listen for event after attributes are saved - Magento 2

Tags: magento2

I have a working event observer hooked to:

```
catalog_product_attribute_update_before
```

However I need the event that fires **after** the attributes have been saved. I had hoped that this would be:

```
catalog_product_attribute_update_after
```

but this is not firing. What event should I be listening for?

Furthermore if this event exists how should I get $product objects from the updated products. In my current class *(listening for: catalog_product_attribute_update_before)* I do the following:

```
public function execute( \Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer ) {

    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();

    foreach ($observer->getData('product_ids') as $key => $prodID) :

        $objectManager->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load( $prodID );

        $product = $this->getProduct( $prodID );

    endforeach;

}
```

Comment: you are looking for an event dispatched when the product attribute instance is saved or when a value of an attribute for a specific product is changed?

Comment: I'm after an event fired after saving products that are edited in bulk on the catelog page of admin

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is the event `catalog_product_attribute_update_before` dispatched in `Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Action::updateAttributes()`.
There is no event for after the update.
but in Magento 2 every public method has 3 events by default. Well...they are not actually events, they are called plugins.
You can execute code before, after and instead of a certain method.
So you can execute some code around the method `updateAttributes` is executed.
You actually need to execute something after it ends, but you don't have access to the parameters when using the `after` interceptor.
Something like this:

Create a file called `di.xml` in your module with this content:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Action">
        <plugin name="update-attributes" type="[Namespace]\[Module]\Model\Plugin\UpdateAttributes" />
    </type>
</config>
```

and this class:  `app/code/[Namespace]/[Module]/Model/Plugin/UpdateAttributes.php`

```
<?php
namespace [Namespace]\[Module]\Model\Plugin;

use Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Action\Interceptor;

class UpdateAttributes
{
    /**
     * @param Interceptor $interceptor
     * @param \Closure $closure
     * @param $productIds
     * @param $attrData
     * @param $storeId
     * @return Interceptor
     */
    public function aroundUpdateAttributes(
        Interceptor $interceptor,
        \Closure $closure,
        $productIds,
        $attrData,
        $storeId
    ) {
        //execute the original method and remember the result;
        $result = $closure($productIds, $attrData, $storeId);
        //do something with $productIds here
        return $result;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a great answer!